# Plot issue : put a legend instead of a top label

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, legending, scripting

I have an issue about putting a legend consisted of a text and numerical value instead of a label.

For example, with this command line :

```
ωBD=9900;
pl = ListLinePlot[{ScaleFactorPast,ScaleFactorFuture},PlotStyle->{Blue,Blue},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"t","a(t)"},LabelStyle->{FontSize->20,FontFamily->"Helvetica",Black,Bold},PlotRange->All, ImageSize->{600},Epilog->{Style[Text["Now",{0,1.4}],24],PointSize[.02],Point[{0, 1}]}, PlotLabel -> Row[{Subscript[ω, BD], "=", ωBD}]]
```

which generates the following plot :

[image: right label]

Now, I would like to have the same label (text=omega_BD = numerical value associated) but
in a legend box with same rendring than for the simple label printing.

I would like to put it either with a smart way (like in Python Matplotlib `loc='best'` or
at the bottom right (where there is some void).

I don't know how to perform this, i.e put the initial label into a legend with `ListLinePlot` function.

Any tracks or suggestions are welcome.

**UPDATE 1** : This solution doesn't work :

```
 pl = ListLinePlot[{ScaleFactorPast,ScaleFactorFuture},PlotStyle->{Blue,Blue},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"t","a(t)"},LabelStyle->{FontSize->20,FontFamily->"Helvetica",Black,Bold},PlotRange->All, ImageSize->{600},Epilog->{Style[Text["Now",{0,1.4}],24],PointSize[.02],Point[{0, 1}]}];
legend =
  LineLegend[{Black}, {Row[{Subscript[\[Omega], BD],
      "=", \[Omega]BD}]},
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0,
       Background -> White] &),
   LegendLabel ->
    Style["The legend is shown on top", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17,
      Blue],
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 24, Black, Italic, Bold}];
Legended[Show[pl], Placed[legend, {0, 1}]]
pics = Join[pics, {
Text[Style["Scale factor behavior for BD"], Background->Hue[0.45, 0.5, 1]],
pl
}];
Export["output/BD_plot.png", pl];
Pause[5]
```

see the result below :

[image: no legend box]

No box legend appears, I have missed something but what ?

**UPDATE 2:** Here the results with you copy/paste code.

[image: missing legend box]

As you can see, only a black big point and the text "Now" appear, no box legend.

**UPDATE 3** : the script generates a legend as expected but only `Mathematica`. Actually, from the beginning, I launch directly the script from command line terminal by doing :

```
$ wolframscript script_plot.wls
```

I would be curious to know why it works in `Mathematica` and not with `wolframscript` interpreter.

Maybe there is a workaround to get the same figure with `wolframscript` interpreter ?

Comment: It might be a good idea to either unaccept my answer so people can have a look at what's going on, or ask a new question along the lines of `differences between mathematica and wolframscript`. I am just suggesting this so you can receive more attention to your issue. Also, the second option might be better for site maintenance bit the more experienced users should know better.

Comment: I have unaccept your answer, don't blame me, we have found at least on Mathematica the same plot. Regards

Comment: No blame at all. Don't worry about it :) Just a suggestion: perhaps you should start by saying that you are running `wolframscript` on a mac and update the title of the question as well, so the rest of users are aware. It's a significant piece of information and in my opinion it should not be at the end of the question. That's the main issue. As you said, in a `Mathematica` notebook my suggested solution works ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate some random data

```
ScaleFactorPast = RandomReal[10, 100];
ScaleFactorFuture = RandomReal[5, 100];
```

**Edit: addressing the comment by the author of the OP**

then we do

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[{ScaleFactorPast, ScaleFactorFuture}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "a(t)"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, 
     Bold}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {600}];
legend = 
  LineLegend[{Black}, {Row[{Subscript[\[Omega], BD], 
      "=", \[Omega]BD}]}, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
       Background -> White] &), 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Style["The legend is shown on top", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17,
      Blue], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 24, Black, Italic, Bold}];
Legended[Show[p1], Placed[legend, {.5, 1.05}]]
```

> [image: update]

To change the position just manipulated the numbers in the [`Placed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html) command. Example

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[{ScaleFactorPast, ScaleFactorFuture}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "a(t)"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, 
     Bold}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {600}];
legend = 
  LineLegend[{Black}, {Row[{Subscript[\[Omega], BD], 
      "=", \[Omega]BD}]}, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
       Background -> White] &), 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Style["The legend is shown on top", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17,
      Blue], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 24, Black, Italic, Bold}];
Legended[Show[p1], Placed[legend, {.3, .2}]]
```

> [image: update3]

---

**Original answer**

---

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[{ScaleFactorPast, ScaleFactorFuture}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "a(t)"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, 
     Bold}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {600}];
legend = 
  LineLegend[{Black}, {Row[{Subscript[\[Omega], BD], 
      "=", \[Omega]BD}]}, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Style["The legend is shown on top", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17,
      Blue], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 24, Black, Italic, Bold}];
Legended[Show[p1], Placed[legend, {.5, 1.05}]]
```

> [image: plot2]

---

**Final edit: a screenshot**

The code for the screenshot so the author of the OP can copy and paste easily

```
ScaleFactorPast = RandomReal[10, 100];
ScaleFactorFuture = RandomReal[5, 100];
\[Omega]BD = 9900;
pl = ListLinePlot[{ScaleFactorPast, ScaleFactorFuture}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "a(t)"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, 
     Bold}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {600}, 
   Epilog -> {Style[Text["Now", {3.1, 1.7}], 24], PointSize[.02], 
     Point[{0, 1}]}];
legend = 
  LineLegend[{Black}, {Row[{Subscript[\[Omega], BD], 
      "=", \[Omega]BD}]}, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
       Background -> White] &), 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Style["The legend is shown on top", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17,
      Blue], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 24, Black, Italic, Bold}];
Legended[Show[pl], Placed[legend, {.35, .25}]]
```

> [image: screenshot]

---

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Actually, **I have mainly need to put a box legend inside the plot** since there is some permanent void space (always on the bottom right of my figure) : how can I specify this location ? I know in python that matplotlib allows to put legend at different locations without indicating the (x,y) coordinates inside. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if possible, I would like to get a box legend

Comment: @stefan I am showing you how to do both of those things in the updated version. Can you please have a look and let me know if that's what you wanted?

Comment: fine ! this is exactly what I wanted, Best egards

Comment: @stefan glad I was able to help :)

Comment: @stefan . Sorry, I can't manage to apply your code snippet. Could you see what's wrong in my case ? you can see the **UPDATE**. Regards

Comment: @stefan sure, I can have a look. Can you tell me what version you are using?

Comment: I am using `WolframScript 1.7.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)`

Comment: @stefan I was talking about the `Mathematica` version you have installed. In your update you missed a chunk of the code I wrote that puts the frame around the legend, i.e you don't have `LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
    Background -> White] &)`. Is this what you meant when you said that it does not work?

Comment: @also, please keep in mind that I don't have access to your data. I am using random numbers. You need to play a bit with the numbers in`Placed[legend, {number1, number2}]` for correct placement. I can add a screenshot of my laptop if you want.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 13 student version.

Comment: @stefan I am also using `V13.0.0`. In my post now you can find a screenshot. The code works as it should, but you just dropped some chunks of it. Do you agree with the screenshot?

Comment: Ok, I have provide in my **UPDATE** the last snippet code I have tried. You see something wrong at first sight ?

Comment: @stefan when I run your last update I get errors. Not sure how you are not getting any. If you just copy and paste what I have presented in my solution above it works as I am showing from my screenshot. Do you agree with me on that? If yes, I am telling you that I **cannot** place exactly the boxed legend if I don't have access to your data. I hope you can understand that.

Comment: @stefan I just added the code in the last update so you can copy and paste easily. Can you please try that particular code with random data and tell me if you get a correct output. You should be obtaining something similar to mine. I will wait for your answer and then I will try to guide you

Comment: I am going to test it right now, thanks

Comment: @stefan it's against the rules to have too extended comment sections for discussions. There's a [`chat room`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135561/discussion-between-bmf-and-stefan) where you can send a message

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) option with relative position syntax of [`Placed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html).

With

```
ωBD = 9900;
baseStyle = {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, Bold};
```

Then

```
Plot[x^2
 , {x, 0, 3}
 , PlotLegends ->
  Placed[
   {Style[Row[{Subscript[ω, BD], "=", ωBD}], baseStyle]}
   , {{.05, .95}, {0, 1}}
   ]
 , BaseStyle -> baseStyle
 , Frame -> True
 ]
```

> [image]

`Placed` can take `Top`, `Bottom`, and others.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. Could you indicate me the meaning of `{.05, .95}, {0, 1}}` ? : I don't know the utility of `{0,1}` . Regards

Comment: @stefan `{scaled position in the plot, scaled position in the legend}`. So `{0,1}` is top left-hand corner.

Comment: fine ! and what about the firs couple `{.05, .95}` ?

Comment: That is the scaled position in the plot, x-y scaled coordinates.

Comment: I make confusions between these 2 couples ? I only need a couple, not ?